# Need to stream Excel file to web clients

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, datatable, openxml

I have a method that converts a SQL query into a `DataView` and now I'm trying to convert a `DataView` to an Excel document that can be streamed from an asp.net site.

I've tried generating a .csv file but Excel would mess up the format.
Then tried OpenXML it appears super slow.

I just need to write out some basic table data so it can be modified in Excel and re-imported.

Comment: What do you mean by "Excel would mess up the format"?

Comment: When you open an .csv file in Excel, Excel will change the format of the data.

Comment: @JonC - Have you seen [this blog post](http://bytebar.blogspot.com/2007/05/c-dataview-to-excel-spreadsheet.html)? It sounds like something that could be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creating an excel file you could use the Infragistics Excel engine.  There is an example of how to create an excel file from a DataTable here: http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/ASPNET/Current/CLR3.5/?page=ExcelEngine_Populating_a_Worksheet_from_a_DataSet.html

You could then load the data again from the excel file format as well.  If you want to test this you could do so with a trial of NetAdvantage for ASP.NET if you don't already have this:
http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/aspnetdownloads.aspx